# Get matching overload based on argument types

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

My objective is to make function that takes function and list of arguments and returns that function signature. It sounds simple at first but main use of it would be to help recognize which function overload got chosen for specific arguments and templates are not that helpful for me here. I have already found code on stack that allows me to print type of any variable, but getting pointer to matching overload is another story.
My first attempt was as follows:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto sig(F f, Args... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...), void()) {
    std::cout << get_name<decltype(f)>() << '\n';
}
```

And it works... as long as function has no overloads. For example:

```
void foo(bool) {}
void fun(double&&) {}
void fun(int&&) {}
```

With these functions I can do

```
sig(foo, true);
```

but not

```
sig(fun, 5.5);
```

After some googling I came with

```
template<typename... A>
using sign = decltype(fun(std::declval<A>()...))(*)(A...);
```

It requires some macros to work with any function(fun is hardcoded for now), but thats ok. Problem is it basically only checks IF there is matching overload and returned signature is only correct about return type.

At this point I'm quite at loss what to try next and my google-fu is failing. I'd appreciate some help with that. [Here is link to wandbox if anyone wants to play with what is already done.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MtJyQV2l3FmC9yGe)

Answer (score 1):

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... )
```

Now,

```
 sig(OVERLOADS_OF(fun), 5.5);
```

does what you want.

There is a [post-C++17 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0573r0.html) to simplify this to

```
#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) =>  __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... )
```

or

```
 sig([](auto&&x)=>fun(decltype(x)(x)), 5.5);
```

or even briefer variants.

Comment: Can you post a link to the proposal? Just curious. Thank you.

Comment: @skyp linked above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What you gave me allows me to create a proxy for function overload and makes it possible to call sig on it - that's cool, I didn't know it could be done thath way. However calling `sig(OVERLOADS_OF(fun), 5.5);` under gcc prints `main()::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)>` so I am still left without information which overload got chosen - specifically what kind of arguments it declared it accepts - and that is what I'm after.

Comment: @stoic Ah, I get it.  I believe there is no way to exctract the signature of an overload resoution without help from the writer of `fun`'s overloads, or a restricted set of possible arguments.